# IOS application Force to use English as Language

Tags: ios, localization, nsuserdefaults

now my app needs to be running in english but when i run the application for the first time the default language of the device is used .

i tried this code :

```
    @autoreleasepool {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"en_US" forKey:@"AppleLocale"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"en_EN" forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

the problem remains , the first run of the application is wrong , but if you close the application and reopen it english is the default language any help ?

Comment: There is no way to do this correctly.  If your app needs to be in English always, then convert it to not consult the system language at all.

Answer (score 2):

You should customize LocalizedString like this. When you start application, use UserDefaults to get language key, not use by default system

```
typedef enum{
e_language_japanese,
e_language_english
}ENUM_LANGUAGE;

NSString* NSCustomLocalizedString( NSString *key , NSString *comment)
{
 NSString *rs = nil;
 if( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:KEY_LANGUAGE ] ==  e_language_japanese)
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-ja",nil);
}
else
{
    rs = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(key,@"Localizable.strings-en",nil);
}
return rs;
}
```

Comment: where to use this .. and is this safe ?

Comment: Instead of using NSLocalizedString, you use this custom localized! I use this, it works until now! It is not belong to system, just belongs to key you set (en or ja)